# Finding unknown when $0/0$

Tags: calculus

Here [Inderteminate(variable)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indeterminate_%28variable%29) written that  $$"x={a-2\over 3-b}$$ while for b = 3 the problem either has no solution at all, or, if also a = 2, it admits any value for x as solution."
$$$$My question is how in the case where $a=2,b=3$ $x$ admits any value, isn't it gives $0/0$?
$$$$Thank you for any help you can provide.

Comment: This one is simple: unless there's a sound definition/axiomatic treatment and etc., this is one of the not-so-rare-but-also-not-so-common nonsenses one can find in Wikipedia.

Comment: Or it is possible, as Hurkyl's answer shows, to quote out of context...

Comment: Sorry, I  quoted out of context because I hadn't understood it properly.

Answer (score 4):

You've made a common mistake: you divided by something you didn't know was nonzero.

Notice that wikipedia was careful:

> Then, provided $b$ is not 3, we can solve for $x$, to find
>   $$x = (a-2)/(3-b)$$

This approach only works when $b$ is not 3, so that $3-b$ is known to be nonzero.

To treat the case where $b=3$ -- and thus $3-b = 0$ -- you have to do something *different*. If you plug $b=3$ into the original equation, things should become clear....

Comment: Yes, it's talking about the solutions of the *original equation*: $2+3x=a+bx$.

Comment: @Hurkyl Thank you very much!!!

Comment: @ Berci Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

It depends. If there also is a relation between $a$ and $b$, say $a=b-1$ or $a=2+\dfrac{b-3}{5}$, then there is a solution.

Comment: Isn't the only relation that is possible $a=b-1$?